# how to add a class to buttons attribute using css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 3px solid #28F2B3;
  color: #28F2B3;
  line-height: 64px;
  background: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222;
  border-radius: 70px;
  -webkit-animation: over 6s infinite;
  animation: over 6s infinite;
}
button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: #28F2B3;
  -webkit-animation: load 6s infinite;
  animation: load 6s infinite;
}
button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px #333, 6px 6px #28F2B3;
  right: 45px;
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-animation: dwd 6s infinite;
  animation: dwd 6s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes over {
  0%, 20% {
    line-height: 64px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
    line-height: 150px;
    border-color: #28F2B3;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    width: 70px;
    border-color: #444;
  }
}
@keyframes over {
  0%, 20% {
    line-height: 64px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
    line-height: 150px;
    border-color: #28F2B3;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    width: 70px;
    border-color: #444;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes load {
  0%, 40% {
    height: 0;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes load {
  0%, 40% {
    height: 0;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dwd {
  0%, 20% {
    right: 45px;
    top: 18px;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    right: 25px;
  }
  30%,
  40%,
  50%,
  60%,
  70%,
  80% {
    top: 14px;
  }
  35%,
  45%,
  55%,
  65%,
  75%,
  85% {
    top: 22px;
  }
  54% {
    color: #28F2B3;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #333, 6px 6px #28F2B3;
  }
  55%,
  85% {
    color: #333;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #28F2B3, 6px 6px #333;
    border-width: 3px;
    height: 15px;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #333;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes dwd {
  0%, 20% {
    right: 45px;
    top: 18px;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    right: 25px;
  }
  30%,
  40%,
  50%,
  60%,
  70%,
  80% {
    top: 14px;
  }
  35%,
  45%,
  55%,
  65%,
  75%,
  85% {
    top: 22px;
  }
  54% {
    color: #28F2B3;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #333, 6px 6px #28F2B3;
  }
  55%,
  85% {
    color: #333;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #28F2B3, 6px 6px #333;
    border-width: 3px;
    height: 15px;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #333;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Download</button>
```

Well I wanted to use this animated button for my personal project but the problem i am having is that my search button also has the same class as the download button so when i save and open the page the download button seems to overlap the search icon. I searched google but didn't find a way to change a button's class using css and i don't know jquery a lot. So if anybody here can help me fix that problem it'll be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: But your button does not have a class here. It seems like your search button is also a `button` and hence it applies to that as well. You should add an `id` or `class` to your button and update the css accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but from the code above, `<button>Download</button>` doesn't have a class. Assuming you have access to the HTML, you can change it to something like `<button class="downloadBtn">` and then target it specifically with the css you have by changing the attributes from `button` to `button.downloadBtn`. Then your other `<button>` tags should not be targeted.

So, a little background: in HTML and CSS, we can use things called `id` and `class` attributes to target specific elements. When you have the css as you showed above, it thinks you want to target every button that is an HTML tag `<button>`. Out of the box, the css has no way of knowing you want to only target a specific button.

What we do in cases like this is utilize the attributes I mentioned. What you can do is make your download button tag look like this:

**HTML**

```
<button id="downloadBtn">Download</button>
```

Then, alter your css to look like this:

**CSS**

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
button#downloadBtn {
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 3px solid #28F2B3;
  color: #28F2B3;
  line-height: 64px;
  background: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222;
  border-radius: 70px;
  -webkit-animation: over 6s infinite;
  animation: over 6s infinite;
}
button#downloadBtn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: #28F2B3;
  -webkit-animation: load 6s infinite;
  animation: load 6s infinite;
}
button#downloadBtn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px #333, 6px 6px #28F2B3;
  right: 45px;
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-animation: dwd 6s infinite;
  animation: dwd 6s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes over {
  0%, 20% {
    line-height: 64px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
    line-height: 150px;
    border-color: #28F2B3;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    width: 70px;
    border-color: #444;
  }
}
@keyframes over {
  0%, 20% {
    line-height: 64px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
    line-height: 150px;
    border-color: #28F2B3;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    width: 70px;
    border-color: #444;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes load {
  0%, 40% {
    height: 0;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes load {
  0%, 40% {
    height: 0;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dwd {
  0%, 20% {
    right: 45px;
    top: 18px;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    right: 25px;
  }
  30%,
  40%,
  50%,
  60%,
  70%,
  80% {
    top: 14px;
  }
  35%,
  45%,
  55%,
  65%,
  75%,
  85% {
    top: 22px;
  }
  54% {
    color: #28F2B3;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #333, 6px 6px #28F2B3;
  }
  55%,
  85% {
    color: #333;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #28F2B3, 6px 6px #333;
    border-width: 3px;
    height: 15px;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #333;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes dwd {
  0%, 20% {
    right: 45px;
    top: 18px;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    right: 25px;
  }
  30%,
  40%,
  50%,
  60%,
  70%,
  80% {
    top: 14px;
  }
  35%,
  45%,
  55%,
  65%,
  75%,
  85% {
    top: 22px;
  }
  54% {
    color: #28F2B3;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #333, 6px 6px #28F2B3;
  }
  55%,
  85% {
    color: #333;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #28F2B3, 6px 6px #333;
    border-width: 3px;
    height: 15px;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #333;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

This way, the css for making the download button look the way you want it to only really targets the download button and not all the buttons. There are a lot of different points we could do into here, but in general, you might want to check out [this article on css syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)

Comment: Perhaps you should edit and show updated code, as OP seems to be a newbie with CSS. Moreover, I think using an `id` would be a better approach in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can give different classes to both of them:

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
button.download-button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 3px solid #28F2B3;
  color: #28F2B3;
  line-height: 64px;
  background: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222;
  border-radius: 70px;
  -webkit-animation: over 6s infinite;
  animation: over 6s infinite;
}
button.download-button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: #28F2B3;
  -webkit-animation: load 6s infinite;
  animation: load 6s infinite;
}
button.download-button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px #333, 6px 6px #28F2B3;
  right: 45px;
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-animation: dwd 6s infinite;
  animation: dwd 6s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes over {
  0%, 20% {
    line-height: 64px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
    line-height: 150px;
    border-color: #28F2B3;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    width: 70px;
    border-color: #444;
  }
}
@keyframes over {
  0%, 20% {
    line-height: 64px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
    line-height: 150px;
    border-color: #28F2B3;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    width: 70px;
    border-color: #444;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes load {
  0%, 40% {
    height: 0;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes load {
  0%, 40% {
    height: 0;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dwd {
  0%, 20% {
    right: 45px;
    top: 18px;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    right: 25px;
  }
  30%,
  40%,
  50%,
  60%,
  70%,
  80% {
    top: 14px;
  }
  35%,
  45%,
  55%,
  65%,
  75%,
  85% {
    top: 22px;
  }
  54% {
    color: #28F2B3;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #333, 6px 6px #28F2B3;
  }
  55%,
  85% {
    color: #333;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #28F2B3, 6px 6px #333;
    border-width: 3px;
    height: 15px;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #333;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes dwd {
  0%, 20% {
    right: 45px;
    top: 18px;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    right: 25px;
  }
  30%,
  40%,
  50%,
  60%,
  70%,
  80% {
    top: 14px;
  }
  35%,
  45%,
  55%,
  65%,
  75%,
  85% {
    top: 22px;
  }
  54% {
    color: #28F2B3;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #333, 6px 6px #28F2B3;
  }
  55%,
  85% {
    color: #333;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px #28F2B3, 6px 6px #333;
    border-width: 3px;
    height: 15px;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #333;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="download-button">Download</button>
```